# Kerberos Two Factor Authentication

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to implement an authentication system for a web based application using Kerberos with an LDAP backend. One of the requirements is that it must have two factor authentication.

What options are available to use two factor authentication with MIT Kerberos, preferably open source?

Answer (score 0):

MIT Kerberos now supports integrated TOTP 2FA and 2FA via RADIUS. Thus via RADIUS nearly all 2FA solutions can be used.

If you are looking for an Opensource solution you could use either http://linotp.org or https://privacyidea.org. (*Disclaimer*: I was/am involved in both).

Comment: I have 2 Java applications on Windows machines. I need to authenticate calls between them using Kerberos or ADFS. I am new to both. Will your solution work for it? I can't seem to find any simple code example.

Comment: I do not understand "authenticate calls between them". You are lucky. You can use an ADFS plugin (https://github.com/sbidy/privacyIDEA-ADFSProvider) to add two factor with privacyIDEA (https://privacyidea.org) to ADFS. Dive into it. There are no easy code examples, because it is not easy.